# Has Subversion lost some of my revisions in a branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I've been working on my project using a Subversion branch. I've used the branching feature a few times before without any issues, until today.

I've come to merge back into the trunk, and noticed that not everything from my branch was there.

I go back to my project folder which I've been committing to the branch and look at the log messages using TortoiseSVN (the command line basic log command shows the same). See the attached image. The revision numbers go up incrementally, until revision 303 (the last trunk revision was 299). Then there are numbers missing.

The revision number of the latest commit, about half an hour ago was 316, but it doesn't show up in the log for the branch. Trying to commit the files again doesn't do anything. I am the only person committing to this repository at present. The missing revisions do not show up in the log for the trunk project.

What's going on here. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Update - the revisions do show in the repository browser (thanks, Antonio Perez), but I don't understand why they are not being included with the merge?**

**Update 2 - I have the answer to why now, but not the solution! It seems that confusion between [VisualSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN) and [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) meant that changes were going to two different branches. Nightmare, but it is sorted out now though! It looks like everyone who answered was sort of right, so thanks!**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it seems you are just getting log (revision history) for your feature branch, and your last revision (316) does not affect that branch. You will get that revision in the log if you request it for the trunk.

Try to open the repo browser and get a log (right click) for the repo root. You may get a clear view of what goes on there looking at the 'Path' column in the revision changes list.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The repo browser does show that the missing revisions exist in the repository, in the branch that I would expect them to be in. So why were they not included with the merge to trunk from that branch?

Comment: Marked as answer as helped me to find the information I was after.

Answer (score 3):

A revision number is SVN repository wide and is not specific to your branch. It will increase for every commit, including trunk and branches.

Answer (score 2):

It shows revisions related to that particular branch. The revision number is, however, repository-wide. If you committed something to the trunk, that new revision wouldn't be shown in your branch log.

Comment: I understand this. I can verify that the missing revisions were committed to the branch in question.